# Does closing ResultSet closes Connection in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i have read number of posts in which people says that does closing connection in `java` closes `resultset`, statements or etc. but i didn't find answer to my question.

i am asking that i am not doing Con.close() but i am doing `rst.close()` so will it close connection or not?

so i just wanna know that does connection get closed when we close `ResultSet` or not?

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: i have read the same post but it does not tells what i am asking

Comment: What would make you think it did? Did you **read the documentation**? --- [`ResultSet.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close--): *A ResultSet object is automatically closed by the Statement object that generated it when that Statement object is closed* --- [`Statement.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close--): *When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.* --- Both say that Statement closes ResultSet, not the other way, so why would you even think that?

Comment: @Andreas You might want to look at JDBC 4.1's [`Statement.closeOnCompletion`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#closeOnCompletion--), closing of a `ResultSet` can close a `Statement`, if that was explicitly requested. But that doesn't extend to `Connection`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel *"if that was explicitly requested"*. If you wrote code to specifically request that closing the `ResultSet` would close the `Statement`, why would you (i.e. OP) ask if it did. You'd already know.

Comment: Your comment says "not the other way", I just point out that it is possible. And honestly, given the OP has posted no code, who knows what he did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word - no.

Closing the `ResultSet` just closes the cursor associated with it so you can't call `next()` on it. The Connection object is not affected, and can be used to execute new statements.

Comment: ok thx. for ur help

Comment: You might want to look at JDBC 4.1's [`Statement.closeOnCompletion`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#closeOnCompletion--), closing of a `ResultSet` can close a `Statement`, if that was explicitly requested. But that doesn't extend to `Connection`.